# Http Communication between 2 docker containers with Docker Compose

Tags: http, docker, docker-compose, identityserver4

I have two docker containers (linux containers on Windows 10 host) that are built from the microsoft/aspnetcore base image. Both containers run fine when I start them individually. I am trying to use Docker Compose to start both containers up (one is an identity provider using IdentityServer4 and the other is an api resource protected by Identity Server). I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:  
  identityserver:
    image: eventloom/identityserver
    build: 
      context: ../Eventloom.Web.IdentityProvider/Eventloom.Web.IdentityProvider
      dockerfile: DockerFile    
    ports: 
      - 8888:80 
  eventsite:
    image: eventloom/eventsite
    build:
      context: ./Eventloom.Web.Eventsite
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    links: 
      - identityserver
    depends_on: 
      - identityserver
    environment:
      IdentityServer: "http://identityserver"
```

the startup class for the "eventsite" container uses IdentityModel to ping the Discovery endpoint of "identityserver". For some reason, the startup is never able successfully get the discovery information, even though I can log into the eventsite container and get ping responses from identityserver. Is there something else I need to do to allow eventsite to communicate over port 80 with identityserver?

Comment: can you give error logs ?

Comment: I can see that you are using depends_on and links in your docker-compose file. you only need to use one of them (they do the same thing) .  Make sure you are using the service name in your configuration files to make the different container communicate with each other.

Comment: Don't use links (they're deprecated). When you use a modern version of docker-compose, the containers are automatically networked together by default. For example, you can access identityserver from within the eventsite container at the hostname `identityserver`. Change the service name to whatever hostname you want.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the HTTP communication was working fine and using the internal DNS properly. The issue was with my IdentityModel.DiscoveryClient object and not configuring it to allow HTTP only. I had to use VS to debug as the app was starting inside the container to figure it out. Thanks.